# Keeping unchanged observed values after kriging interpolation

Tags: kriging

Is there a way to force kriging to keep unchanged measured values of observation points?

For example: if the observed value of a location is 1, after the interpolation it could be 0.9 or even 0.5, depending on the other locations' values. I'd like to have 1 for that observed location after the prediction too.

I know that, considering the kriging formula, this is a stretch but predicting values where it is actually known seems to me a stretch as well. I found that the only prediction method that preserves observation points' values is IDW but this is not the best method to predict values for the other prediction locations.

I'm using R and the package "intamap".

I'm using the "automatic" method provided by "intamap" package. I need to use it for two reasons: the first is for the very strong skewness of my data and the second reason is that kriging interpolation is the final step of method I'm developing that is devoted to be user friendly for inexpert persons.

"Intamap" package claims to meet these two needs. The reason why I need to keep original data unchanged is that observation points represent the probability values of a phenomenon to occur. Pay attention, I'm not talking about indicator kriging, because observed values are just probabilities. So I need to provide inexpert users the geographical distribution of different degree of probabilities. If I have two observation points with 1 and 0.5 probability values, I need these values to be unchanged and that kriging interpolates the values in the prediction locations between them.

I hope to have been clear in my explanation. How can I proceed now?

Comment: How are you Kriging? If you are using some kind of automated "kriging" procedure you're probably out of luck. But if you can specify the variogram parameters, then there's a lot you can do. By forcing the nugget to zero and selecting a model that is relatively smooth at the origin, you can achieve your aims. But if such a model does not match the empirical variogram well, it's pointless to be kriging in the first place. What you really need to tell us is *why* you want the interpolated surface to honor the data and *how* you will be using that surface.

Comment: My reply is in the improved question

Comment: (1) Skewness does not indicate whether kriging is appropriate, but usually it indicates some preprocessing of the data is needed before doing any kriging, such as an initial nonlinear transformation. (2) Kriging is the *opposite* of user-friendly: complex, slow, and needing statistical analysis. (3) Kriging can on occasion predict values beyond the range of data. Presenting "probabilities" that are negative or greater than 1 could be a problem! (4) How exactly do you obtain data that are "probabilities"? Are these perhaps observed *frequencies*? There are crucial distinctions between the two.

Comment: @whuber, sorry if I let you understand that skewness should be related to kriging. As I considered kriging the most accurate interpolation, I used a package that let me use it even with non gaussian data by automatically selecting the method (like copula, for example) that best fits my data. Yes, I know that kriging is not user friendly. The probabilities are computed by a bayesian process that involves the occurrences of different events at the observed locations and the values spans from 1 to 0.001. Arcosin transformation doesn't changes too much the distribution.

Comment: Kriging is not "most accurate" in *any* sense when it is done automatically. You should feel free to consider alternatives for your application.

Comment: Any suggestions or papers to make a choice? Take your time, you are so kind in replying me so quickly!

Comment: There is a large literature on interpolation methods. Making a good choice depends on your application, on why you are interpolating, on the statistical nature of the data, and many more things. There is about a 25 year history now of papers that compare Kriging to alternative methods. Their results depend on the nature of the data and the skills of the analysts. An early paper in this area is Englund, EJ, [*A Variance of Geostatisticians*](http://www.epa.gov/esd/cmb/research/papers/ee102.pdf): *Math. Geo.* **22:4** (1990), pp 417-455.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is kriging an exact interpolation method?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114676/is-kriging-an-exact-interpolation-method)

Answer (score 2):

Kriging is an exact interpolator. You don't have to do anything. Check your settings if it is not.

[image: from wikipedia]

Comment: It is misleading to characterize kriging as "exact" because the surfaces it interpolates can be nondifferentiable and even discontinuous. When there is a nonzero nugget in the variogram, the interpolated surfaces will *not* look like your diagram. Instead, they will *miss* the original data points. If you plug in the *precise* coordinates of the original data points it will return the original values: basically, it leaps from its *non-exact* interpolated surface to the data points and right back again.  That is not what is wanted here.

Comment: whuber: I disagree. Even with a nonzero nugget the surface will not miss the original points (in ordinary and simple kriging)

Comment: Johanvdw, You are not disagreeing with me, but you may be failing to appreciate what you are saying. Yes, kriging with a nonzero nugget "honors" the data. But it does so only by creating a discontinuous surface that jumps away from the interpolated values at the data points! In practice, the kriged surface is evaluated at the centers of a grid of points and none of those centers is *exactly* located at a data point. Thus, the interpolated surface that actually gets mapped fails to honor the data.

Comment: I still disagree: the surface will be smooth.

Comment: Assuming you mean the *theoretical* surface that *does* honor the data, I challenge you to prove it, then.  The textbooks--as well as any test--will show you are wrong. If you mean the *mapped* surface, I have just explained why it appears smooth--but then it does *not* honor the data.

Comment: For reference, please see Cressie, *Statistics for Spatial Data* (1991), section 3.2.1: "Thus, kriging can either honor the data ... or smooth the data.  The larger is [the nugget], the more one smooths. ... Equation (3.2.28) shows the extreme lengths the kriging predictor ... will go to be an exact interpolator." (That equation states that for a pure nugget effect, the Kriging interpolator is the arithmetic mean of all the data *except* at the data points, where it equals their original values.)

Comment: @joanvdw, you are, in fact, incorrect! The nugget is intended to model error. If the nugget is 0 then Kriging is exact however, with an error term it becomes inexact. This is inherent in Kriging equations and is a well known quantity. It is exceeding rare that there is no nugget effect. If you would like to see the matrix equation that demonstrates the nugget effect see page 8 in this document: http://wiredspace.wits.ac.za/jspui/bitstream/10539/11193/11/11_CHAPTER%203.pdf